# Set a regex pattern to identify a repeating pattern of an enumeration, where the same match is repeated an unknown number of successive times

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

```py
import re

input_text = "hjshhshs el principal, amplio, de gran importancia, y más costoso hotel de la zona costera. Es una sobrilla roja, bastante amplia y incluso cómoda de llevar. Hay autos rápidos, más costosos, y veloces. también, hay otro tipo de autos menos costosos"

direct_subject_modifiers = r"((?:\w+))"
modifier_connectors = r"(?:(?:,\s*|)y|(?:,\s*|)y|,)\s*(?:(?:(?:a[úu]n|todav[íi]a|incluso)\s+|)(?:de\s*gran|bastante|un\s*tanto|un\s*poco|)\s*(?:m[áa]s|menos)\s+|)"

regex = modifier_connectors + direct_subject_modifiers

matches = re.finditer(regex, input_text, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

input_text = re.sub(matches, lambda m: (f"\(\(DESCRIP\){m[1]}\)"), input_text, re.IGNORECASE)
print(repr(input_text))
```

How to build regex to detect a successive description of n elements that coincide in these 2 patterns `regex = modifier_connectors + direct_subject_modifiers` , repeating themselves an unknown number of times?

The output after identifying the elements in the string, and placing them in parentheses, keep in mind that within the same string there can be more than one pattern that must be encapsulated between parentheses, in this example there are 3 of them.

```
"hjshhshs el ((DESCRIP)principal, amplio, de gran importancia, y más costoso) hotel de la zona costera. Es una sobrilla ((DESCRIP)roja, bastante amplia y incluso cómoda) de llevar. Hay autos ((DESCRIP)Hay autos rápidos, más costosos, y veloces). también, hay otro tipo de autos menos costosos"
```

Comment: Remember that not everything needs a regexp. Sometimes it's okay to use a normal tokenizer, written specifically for the one use case, easy to read, understand, and maintain.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The truth is that I can't think of a tokenizer for an enumeration, I thought about the regex x because it's the same pattern that is always repeated. When an enumeration is a comma and then the enumeration (in this particular case the adjectives in the example are). I tried to use the re.finditer() method, but it gives me an error when assembling the whole pattern and use it in the re.sub()

Comment: Can you also show your expected result/matching after showing example input?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I was trying to directly send the pattern by avoiding finditer(), but it's impossible. Following what the documentation of this method indicates, everything should be fine, but this code gives me an error `raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")`

Comment: Why do you expect "bastante amplia" to appear in one match? I don't see `modifier_connectors` going to match any part of that, and since it is not one word, the `direct_subject_modifiers` is not going to do it either. What is the logic?

Comment: Sorry, when I shortened the pattern to fit into the question, I accidentally removed the word `"bastante"`. Now I have edited the question and added to the pattern stored in the variable `modifier_connectors` the condition of `"bastante"`.  Now if the modifiers of the adjectives should be able to serve.

Comment: @trincot Regarding the pattern stored in `direct_subject_modifiers` It should not have changes, since its objective is to match a word without spaces that is in the enumeration. Thus obtaining the search sequence `regex = modifier_connectors + direct_subject_modifiers`. which is repeated an unknown number of times.

Comment: The edit now makes the regex invalid. The parentheses are not balanced.

Comment: @trincot I have edited the `modifier_connectors` regex pattern so that it does not have problems with unbalanced apparentesis, now it throws the `raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")` error again in the `re.sub()` line

Comment: In `modifier_connectors` everything after the comma or `y` is optional. Is this intended? If so then why should the total regex not match `también, hay` as it is a sequence of two words separated by a short `modifier_connectors` match (just a comma and space)?

Comment: @trincot As the `direct_subject_modifiers = r"((?:\w+))"` pattern is prepared to recognize an alphanumeric string without spaces, one way to maintain the sequence continuity even in these special cases, is to add some optional words to the modifier connectors so that they do not interfere in those cases. Those words after the comma without intentionally optional, if I use an example in the English language, it would be: `"the bird is red, quite fast and very noisy"`, in that case I have added `"quite"` and `"very"` as optional words

Comment: I don't really see how that answers my question. Are you saying `también, hay` should be matched, or should it not? By which rule?

Comment: in the sequence `"Hay autos rápidos, más costosos. también, hay otro tipo"` , there is a dot `"."` in the middle.  `", más costosos. también"`. and therefore that part should not be captured

Comment: I'm not speaking of what comes before `también`. I am considering a match that *starts* at that word. Are you saying that a match should never be preceded by a point?

Comment: Because in an enumeration there are at least 2 or more enumerated objects `r"((?:\w+))"`, and in that case this pattern does not repeat.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. There is a sequence here of two words, separated by a comma.

Comment: `"este auto es rojo"` should not be a sequence that should be captured, however `"este auto es rojo y rapido"` and `"este auto es rojo, bastante rápido, y bonito"` are sequences that should be captured

Comment: I don't understand the rules. I give up.

Comment: `modifier_connectors + direct_subject_modifiers` The criterion is that this pattern must be repeated at least 2 consecutive times. in the first example `"este auto es rojo"` that pattern only repeated once, so you shouldn't capture that line, but in the example  `"este auto es rojo, bastante rápido, y bonito"` the pattern was repeated 2 consecutive times, and that is a case that should be captured

Comment: @trincot That's the problem I was having, the regex must be repeated at least 2 times for it to be considered an object enum, and if it's only once, you shouldn't capture it.

Comment: But then why do you expect `rápidos, más costosos` to match? It seems to only have one `modifier_connectors`, yet you write it should repeat twice....

Comment: You are right, I edited the question there, because there is an error when I try to build the string , it would look like this "rápidos, más costosos, y veloces"

Comment: @trincot Sorry, now with that input it could be followed that logic, since it completes 2 repetitions. Anyway, I don't know how you would do to count the repetitions?

Comment: @trincot  Now that the input example is fine, would using the re.finditer() method be fine? Or is there another better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some of the issues with the regex and code:

- As the first regex does not match spacing, the second regex should allow for spaces *before* and *after* the words it matches. This was not done consistently (e.g. after "de gran" no space was matched).
- As your text contains accented letters, you would need to apply the `re.UNICODE` modifier, so `\w` will also match those.
- To avoid false positives, you'd better also add some `\b` in the regex, to make sure `y` doesn't match in `hay` and similar issues.
- `re.sub` expects a regex as first argument, not the matches from `re.finditer`
- `re.sub` expects the flags as 5<sup>th</sup> argument, not 4<sup>th</sup>
- `m[1]` will only reproduce what the first capture group matched, while you need all the matched text to be reproduced here. This would be `m[0]`, but see comment below.

Not a problem, but there is a `?` operator you could use. It could be used instead of adding empty alternatives with `(   |)`.

The `re.sub` callback is not needed. You can provide a string literal as second argument and reproduce the matched string with `\g<0>`.

As to the main question: you can use the `{2,}` quantifier to repeat a pattern at least twice.

Here is the code I ended up with:

```
import re

input_text = "hjshhshs el principal, amplio, de gran importancia, y más costoso hotel de la zona costera. Es una sobrilla roja, bastante amplia y incluso cómoda de llevar. Hay autos rápidos, más costosos, y veloces. también, hay otro tipo de autos menos costosos"

direct_subject_modifiers = r"((?:\w+))"
# always match prefix and postfix spaces
modifier_connectors = r"\s*(?:\by\s+|,\s*(?:y\s+)?)\b(?:(?:a[úu]n|todav[íi]a|incluso)?(?:de\s*gran|m[áa]s|menosde\s*gran|bastante|(?:un\s*tanto|un\s*poco)?\s*(?:m[áa]s|menos))?)\b\s*"  

regex = direct_subject_modifiers + "(?:" + modifier_connectors  + direct_subject_modifiers + "){2,}"

"""
Added Unicode mode, to match accented letters too
First arg should be the regex. 
No need for callback argument. Just back reference with g<0>
No need to escape parentheses in the replacement string
"""

input_text = re.sub(regex, r"((DESCRIP)\g<0>)", input_text, flags=re.I | re.U)
print(repr(input_text))
```

Output:

> 'hjshhshs el ((DESCRIP)principal, amplio, de gran importancia, y más costoso) hotel de la zona costera. Es una sobrilla ((DESCRIP)roja, bastante amplia y incluso cómoda) de llevar. Hay autos ((DESCRIP)rápidos, más costosos, y veloces). también, hay otro tipo de autos menos costosos'

On a final note: language grammar is too complex to be parsed with regular expressions. You'll always bump into examples where the regex based solution falls short... and the code will become hard to maintain. Tokenising the input and then applying rules via code will be easier to manage.

Comment: Really thanks for the help, and sorry for the errors in the question, when I tried to simplify the input, I did not take into account certain aspects that would harm the detection by regex